# ng-repeat over an array of objects

Tags: javascript, angularjs

Using ng-repeat, how would I loop through the following:

```
var  messages : [
      {text:"Standard Message"},
      {text:"Success Message!", type:"success"},
      {text:"Alert Message!", type : "alert"},
      {text:"secondary message...", type : "secondary"}
    ]
```

I've tried:

```
<p ng-repeat="message in messages">{{message}}</p>
```

and it doesn't seem to work, how would I do this?

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/aurDq/ .. or read the front page tutorial

Comment: I am not sure why this question has been marked off-topic as the OP has shown 'what he is trying to do' by showing the html markup, and the accepted answer shows what he was missing. Although primitive, I happen to see such questions all the time on SO, and rightfully so, as the OP has missed something very tiny on which he has spent a lot of time, and other people are there to point out the tiny mistake. This question is not vague imho to be marked off-topic.

Answer (score 38, accepted):

You need to insert your messages array into the $scope:

```
$scope.messages = [
      {text:"Standard Message"},
      {text:"Success Message!", type:"success"},
      {text:"Alert Message!", type : "alert"},
      {text:"secondary message...", type : "secondary"}
    ]
```

and then use it as following:

```
<p ng-repeat="message in messages">{{message.text}}</p>
```

Comment: Weird, now {{message}} is even working. I was looking to dump out the object. Oh well, works now, not sure what was wrong..

Comment: @ChrisChevalier  I don't understand your question, can you elaborate?

Comment: He doesn't understand for `X in Y`.  @DorCohen, it is looping over the array. For each `message` in `$scope.messages` - it isn't singular/plural. You can use any variable (although it is a quite common convention). For instance, it could have been written `<p ng-repeat="x in messages">{{x.text}}</p>`